# I would like to use the same view to display or update an object through his django form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Someone could help me with this problem ?

models.py

```
@autoconnect
class Event(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
  slug = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=' ', blank=True)
  description = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
  PrivacityType = ((1, 'Público'), (2, 'Privado'))
  privacity = models.IntegerField(choices=PrivacityType, default=1, blank=True)
  EVENT_TYPE = ((1, 'Deporte'), (2, 'Nutrición'), (3, 'Salud'))
  type = models.IntegerField(choices=EVENT_TYPE, default=1)
  owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
  creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
  updated_date= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  start = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
  end = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
  address = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='', blank=True)
  notes = models.CharField(max_length=250, default='', blank=True)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title

  def pre_save(self):
    self.slug = self.title.replace(" ", "_").lower()
```

forms.py

```
class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):
  title = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Título'}))
  description = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Descripción'}))
  address = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Lugar'}))
  notes =forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Añade tus notas'}))

  class Meta:
    model = event_models.Event
    fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
class EventUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
  model = events_models.Event
  template_name = 'event.html'
  fields = ['title', 'description']
  slug_field = 'slug'
  slug_url_kwarg = 'slug'
  context_object_name = 'event'
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^eventos/(?P<slug>\w+)/$', calendar_views.EventUpdateView.as_view(), name='detail_event'),
url(r'^eventos/nuevo/$', calendar_views.add_event, name='add_event'),
```

event.html:

```
{% extends "calendar.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load calendar_tags %}

{% block event %}

<!-- Event Information Area -->
  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 smt-30 xmt-30">
    <div class="map-contacts">
      <!--<form id="contact-form" method="POST">-->
      <form action="{% url 'calendar:detail_event' event_slug=event.slug %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}

        <!-- Event Form Area -->
        <div class="single-contact-form">
            <div class="contact-box subject">
              <h3>Privacidad</h3>
              {{ event.privacity }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Event Form Area -->
        <div class="single-contact-form">
            <div class="contact-box subject">
              <h3>Categoría</h3>
              {{ event.type }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Event Form Area -->
        <div class="single-contact-form">
            <div class="contact-box subject">
              {{ event.title }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Event Form Area -->
        <div class="single-contact-form">
            <div class="contact-box subject">
              {{ event.description }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Event Form Area -->
        <div class="single-contact-form">
            <div class="contact-box subject">
              {{ event.address }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Event Form Area -->
        <div class="single-contact-form">
            <div class="contact-box subject">
              <h3>Inicio</h3>
              {{ event.start }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Event Form Area -->
        <div class="single-contact-form">
            <div class="contact-box subject">
              <h3>Fin</h3>
              {{ event.end }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Event Form Area -->
        <div class="single-contact-form">
            <div class="contact-box subject">
              <h3>Privacidad</h3>
              {{ event.notes }}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="contact-btn">
            <input type="submit" class="fv-btn" value="Modificar">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

{% endblock %}
```

The template call:

```
<a href="{% url 'calendar:detail_event' event.slug %}">{{ event.title }}</a>
```

This is the error that appears.
How can i fix it ?

Reverse for 'detail_event' with keyword arguments '{u'event_slug': u'evento_1'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'calendario/eventos/(?P\w+)/$']

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is calling `eventos` rather than `events`?

Comment: I have translated it. It's already corrected.

Comment: def event(request, event_slug): -> def event(request, event_slug=None):

Comment: are you passing u'event_slug value to to event url in html

Comment: The event_slug=None has changed there error, now it's `NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'detail_event' with keyword arguments '{u'event_slug': <django.forms.boundfield.BoundField object at 0x10767b590>}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'calendario/events/(?P<event_slug>\\w+)/$']`

Comment: Your `event` is an `EventForm`?

Comment: Yes, the event and the event_form in the view are differents. Here is all the project [https://github.com/AlbertoSanmartinMartinez/HealthyLife]

Comment: Can you show the line in your project's urls.py, where you used 'calendar' as the url name?

Comment: Line 86 in this link: [https://github.com/AlbertoSanmartinMartinez/HealthyLife/blob/master/healthylife/healthylife/urls.py.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach won't work because you need an `event_slug` to reach the form where you will create the event. But the event_slug won't exist until *after* you create the event!

The usual solution is to have separate 'create' and 'update' views. 
Check out the [generic editing views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/) for this purpose. For example, you could navigate to `/event/new/` to create a new event (without slug) and then go to `/event/(?P<slug>\w+)/` to edit that event once the slug exists.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18806703/within-a-template-distinguish-between-create-and-update-form) should also help you out.

Comment: I'm going to do it in separate views and i will write if I have managed to fix it

Comment: I'am revising the code and i want something like this: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/7493320/8000016]. My idea is that if the event exists, initialize the form with the information of the object and start it empty if not exist.

Comment: Django's [UpdateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview) does that automatically (see the example, where you simply choose which fields to render). You just need to use `/events/(?P<slug>\w+)/` (i.e. with `slug` as the keyword not `event_slug`, so that Django automatically knows which object to load. So ultimately, use the UpdateView with the url path above for the edit view, and use a CreateView with `/events/new/` or similar (but no slug).

Comment: @AlbertoSanmartinMartinez Ok, please upvote my solution if it has been helpful, and also mark it as correct if it solves your problem

Comment: Thanks !! I upvoted your comment, but now appears other error, i posted the modifications in the general question and actualize the error message.

Comment: Where is the template call? I don't see it in event.html... You could also make life easier for yourself by deleting the action variable from the form tag: it will just post to the same page by default, without you having to make it work

Comment: The template call for EventUpdateView is in day_calendar.html and month_calendar.html, in each event detail view link. I deleted the action tag form but now the event update view doesn't appear like form, only the information.